# Need some guidance on producing checksums in Perl

Tags: perl, module, checksum

I'm needing to produce a checksum for a bunch of data in Perl, and I came across this Digest::MD5 module.  It looks like it will fit the bill, but I thought I would ask here to see if anyone has any advise or possibly knows of a better module to use or even maybe a more suitable digest algorithm.  What's being hashed is about 10 tables worth of data (one logical tuple at a time).  This will be the first time I make use of checksums, so any tips, tricks, gotchas would be very appreciated.

Edit:  As far as I know, there's nothing wrong with Digest:MD5, but I've never used it nor am I familiar with hash algorithms.  I was hoping someone with experience would be able to tell me if I was on the right track or not.  Just wanted a little bit of confirmation before going too far.

Comment: Could you clarify what you think the problem with `Digest::MD5` might be? If you can't, why don't you just use it?

Comment: What are you going to use the checksums for? Is it just to check the data or is there a security requirement?

Comment: @a'r - it's not for security, only to check data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [Digest::MD5](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest-MD5) will do the trick; it's written by Gisle Aas (author of LWP among other excellent packages) and has [good reviews & ratings on cpanratings](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Digest-MD5), both of which should reassure you that it's a good choice.

Using it can be as simple as:

```
my $checksum =  Digest::MD5::md5_hex($data);
```

If you think you may be likely to change your chosen digest algorithm in future (for instance, using SHA-1 instead), you might want to consider using [Digest](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest) instead - also written by Gisle Aas, and providing an easy interface to various Digest modules.

For example:

```
my $digest = Digest->new('MD5');
$digest->add($data);             # to add data from a scalar, or:
$digest->add_file($filehandle);  # to add data read from a filehandle
my $checksum = $digest->hexdigest;  # or just ->digest for binary
```

That approach has the benefit that you could just change the "MD5" to e.g. "SHA-1", and you're done.

Just for completeness, I'll add why you might want to design with the ability to use other hashing algorithms easily - if this was used for any security purposes, MD5 has been shown to be vulnerable to hash collisions - the US Department of Homeland Security [advises that MD5 "should be considered cryptographically broken and unsuitable for further use"](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/836068).  However, for general checking of data integrity, it's still an acceptable choice for many, and is widely supported.

SHA-1 is also considered weak; SHA-2 is considered the best choice for secure hashing for cryptographic purposes.